# Unique zero solution to a difference equation via Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, integral-transforms, laplace-transform, difference-equations

We want to prove that
the unique solution to the following difference equation is the null one:
$$
au(x)+b\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}(x)u(x+\frac{1}{2})+c\mathbf{1}_{(\frac{1%
}{2},1)}(x)u(x-\frac{1}{2})=0,\text{ }x\in (0,1).
$$
Extending $u$ by zero outside $(0,1)$ and taking the Laplace transform yields
$$
a\int_{0}^{1}e^{-px}u(x)dx+be^{\frac{p}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}%
}^{1}e^{-px}u(x)dx+ce^{-\frac{p}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-px}u(x)dx=0,%
\text{ }p\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
,
$$
that is
$$
\left( a+be^{\frac{p}{2}}\right) \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}e^{-px}u(x)dx+\left(
a+ce^{-\frac{p}{2}}\right) \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-px}u(x)dx=0,\text{ }%
p\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
.
$$
If we let for instance $p=\gamma +4n\pi i,n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
$ with $a+ce^{-\frac{\gamma }{2}}=0$ we get
$$
\left( a+be^{\frac{\gamma }{2}}\right) e^{-\gamma }\int_{\frac{1}{2}%
}^{1}e^{-4n\pi ix}u(x)dx=0,
$$
which yields that $u=0$ on $(\frac{1}{2},1)$ if $a+be^{\frac{\gamma }{2}%
}\neq 0$ which is equivalent to $a^2-bc \neq 0$. With the same manner, by choosing this time  $p=\delta +4n\pi
i,n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
$ with $a+be^{\frac{\delta }{2}}=0$ we get
$$
\left( a+ce^{-\frac{\delta }{2}}\right) e^{-\delta }\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}%
}e^{-4n\pi ix}u(x)dx=0,
$$
so if $a+ce^{-\frac{\delta }{2}}\neq 0$ we get $u=0$ on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, which is equivalent to $a^2-bc \neq 0$.

I don't know if this kind of reasoning is correct since the Laplace
transform of $u$ is zero on subintervals with different choices of $p.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition can be rewritten as the system of three equations:
$$au(x)+bu(x+1/2)=0\ \forall x\in(0,1/2), \tag{1}$$
$$au(x)+cu(x-1/2)=0\ \forall x\in(1/2,1), \tag{2} $$
$$au(1/2)=0. \tag{3} $$
In turn, (2) can be rewritten as
$$cu(x)+au(x+1/2)=0\ \forall x\in(0,1/2). \tag{2a} $$
So, if the determinant $a^2-bc$ of the system (1)--(2a) of linear equations for $u(x),u(x+1/2)$ is nonzero, then $u(x)=u(x+1/2)=0$ $\forall x\in(0,1/2)$, that is, $u(x)=0$ $\forall x\in(0,1)\setminus\{1/2\}$. Together with (3), this yields $u(x)=0$ $\forall x\in(0,1)$ if $a\ne0$.

The cases when $a^2-bc=0$ or $a=0$ are considered similarly.

In particular, if $a^2-bc=0$ but $a\ne0$, then $a\ne0$ and $b\ne0$, then the system (1)--(3) reduces to the conditions
$$u(x)=-(b/a)u(x+1/2)\ \forall x\in(0,1/2)\tag{1a}$$ and $u(1/2)=0$. So, here one may assign any values to $u$ on $(1/2,1)$, and then use (1a) to determine the values of $u$ on $(1/2,1)$.

---

The OP requested in a comment that the solution be given in terms of the Laplace transform, say $L$. This can be done as follows.

Of course, to use the Laplace transform, we have to assume that $u$ is integrable on $(0,1)$. Let
$$U(x):=\begin{cases}u(x)&\text{ if }0<x<1/2,\\ 
0&\text{ if }x>1/2,\end{cases}$$
$$V(x):=\begin{cases}u(x+1/2)&\text{ if }0<x<1/2,\\ 
0&\text{ if }x>1/2.\end{cases}$$
Then (1) and (2) imply
$$aL(U)+bL(V)=0,$$
$$cL(U)+aL(V)=0.$$
So, if $a^2-bc\ne0$, then $L(U)=L(V)=0$ and hence $U=V=0$ almost everywhere (a.e.), so that $u=0$ a.e., so that $u=0$ if $u$ is continuous.

As shown above, there is no uniqueness if $a^2-bc=0$.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have already solved the equation by this approach. The goal us to use Laplace transform to solve the system. The unique approach that I found is what I have written above. I don't know if there is more general approaches to deal with difference equations on bounded domains.

Comment: @Gustave : Why did you not say you had already solved it by this method? Why did you not state your goal, to necessarily use the Laplace transform? And why is that a goal?

Comment: Sorry for this misunderstanding.  The problem that I'm looking for its solution is the same but instead of $1/2$ we put $r$ as a translation step. If $r$ is rational there is no problem since we can always make the decomposition that you have made for the case $r=1/2$. This doesn't work if $r$ is irrational.  My goal is to work on lire general systems but solving them with the decomposition approach seems to be impossible since the determinant of the associated matrix can not be computed.

Comment: So, the most useful way in my opinion is the Laplace transform. The thing is that with the particular choices of $p$ I have the desired result but I can not justify the computations.

Comment: @Gustave : Now you have it for all $p$.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer.

Comment: @Gustave : Will you now mark my answers to this question and to the other one (at https://mathoverflow.net/a/406054/36721) accordingly?

Comment: Yes sir, but I don't now how to mark an answer accordingly?.  Can you explain more sir?

Comment: @Gustave : You may want to look at these guidelines: https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers and https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer